# How to force numpy.genfromtxt to generate a non-structured numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

In Python 3 I do:

```
s = StringIO(u"1,1.3,abcde\n2,1.3,test")
data = numpy.genfromtxt(s, dtype=[int,float,'U10'], delimiter=',', names=None)
```

and I get:

```
array([(1, 1.3, 'abcde'), (2, 1.3, 'test')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U10')])
```

I would like to get a regular numpy array with no names like the following:

```
array([[1, 1.3, 'abcde'], 
        [2, 1.3, 'test']])
```

Is it possible?

Comment: "Regular numpy arrays" only have one data type. If you try your last piece of code, all objects will be strings

Answer (score 1):

With a text list:

```
In [338]: txt = '''1, 1.3, abcde 
     ...: 2, 1.3, def'''.splitlines()
```

The structured array:

```
In [339]: np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None, delimiter=',', encoding=None)          
Out[339]: 
array([(1, 1.3, ' abcde'), (2, 1.3, ' def')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U6')])
```

Trying to specify object - each item its own type:

```
In [340]: np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=object, delimiter=',', encoding=None)        
Out[340]: 
array([[b'1', b' 1.3', b' abcde'],
       [b'2', b' 1.3', b' def']], dtype=object)
```

It doesn't try to convert any strings to numbers.

`converters` converts columns right, but for some reason still makes a structured array:

```
In [341]: np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=object, delimiter=',', encoding=None, convert
     ...: ers={0:int, 1:float})                                                 
Out[341]: 
array([(1, 1.3, b' abcde'), (2, 1.3, b' def')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', 'O')])
```

But you could convert the structured array to object dtype via a list:

```
In [346]: np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None, delimiter=',', encoding=None)          
Out[346]: 
array([(1, 1.3, ' abcde'), (2, 1.3, ' def')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<U6')])
In [347]: np.array(_.tolist(), object)                                          
Out[347]: 
array([[1, 1.3, ' abcde'],
       [2, 1.3, ' def']], dtype=object)
```

Another option is to split the lines yourself, building a list of lists.  `genfromtxt` is doing that with few more bells and whistles.

```
In [357]: lines=[] 
     ...: for line in txt: 
     ...:     i = line.split(',') 
     ...:     x = (int(i[0]), float(i[1]), i[2].strip()) 
     ...:     lines.append(x) 

In [358]: lines                                                                 
Out[358]: [(1, 1.3, 'abcde'), (2, 1.3, 'def')]
In [359]: np.array(lines,object)                                                
Out[359]: 
array([[1, 1.3, 'abcde'],
       [2, 1.3, 'def']], dtype=object)
```

But beware that you can't do math on that object array as well as on a numeric array, or even the numeric fields of the structured array.

Comment: Great and complete answer! Are structured array and record arrays the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

What you got is a "structured array" and it is superior to a "regular array" because it supports heterogeneous data types.  Two of your columns are numbers but one is text, so it doesn't really make sense to collapse your data into a plain `numpy.ndarray` without structure.  But if you want, you can:

```
numpy.array(data.tolist())
```

That will give you an `ndarray` with all strings:

```
array([['1', '1.3', 'abcde'],
       ['2', '1.3', 'test']], dtype='<U32')
```

But this is rarely a good idea.  If we had more context, we might be able to suggest a better overall approach.